# Square UImageView in a Cell of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to place an ImageView in a Cell, I want the Image to be square and to work on most iOS phones, iPhones and iPads.

I'm using constraints to do that, I made an aspect ratio but it doesn't seem to work right.

Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Can you write what are constraints  you have set ?

Comment: is it a custom cell or a standard one?

Comment: Custom cell, and I'm not able to add some constraints as Align (it's disabled)

Answer (score 1):

As said by [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495995/vladimir-k) in the answer [Auto Layout: Square Image View with equal width / height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614454/auto-layout-square-image-view-with-equal-width-height)

you need to set this constrain to your imageview

> First of all try to switch mode from **w:Compact/h:Any** to
>   **w:Any/h:Any**. By adding constraints in this mode you will apply them for all devices and orientations.
>
> Here is list of constraints that you need to apply:
>
> [image]
>
> Set low priority for Equal Width and Equal Height to superview.

Comment: How to add those contraintes

Comment: You need to read proper tutorial to understand which constraints are appliea.

Comment: Google is the best place . You can find according to your understandable launguage. refer you tube and few good blog.